# Post 405 (Method Not Allowed) api symfony angular

Tags: angular, api, symfony

When I went to run [this project api](https://github.com/FlorianLeclercq/bonobo_island_2) with command `http-server -o` 
which talk about  (api Rest with symfony backend and angular frontend) I had this error:

> POST
>   `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/api/src/AppBundle/Controller/MainController.php`
>   405 (Method Not Allowed)angular.js:12265

and this my network:

[image: network]

someone have any idea what's the problem or how i can solve.

this my project in symfony without api angularjs [https://github.com/FlorianLeclercq/bonobos_island](http://github.com/FlorianLeclercq/bonobos_island)

Comment: Can you share how are you defining your routes ?

Comment: Look at the `response` in `network` tab.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some more information about what you expect and what your problem is, you can alse start reading the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think that your url is wrong. Are you sure that is api/scr/appBundle/Controler/mainControler.php ?

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using? You shouldn't be accessing the controller directly but instead define a route. https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html

Comment: You should not access controllers directly, but access "app.php" or "app_dev.php" and use route declared in controller.

Comment: did you mean @MichałSzczech I change my route app_dev/api/scr/appBundle/Controler/mainControler.php ?

Comment: @malcolm did you mean this response in network http://prntscr.com/i1l2xz  and  http://prntscr.com/i1l40e

Comment: @enginer no `headers` but `response` body.

Comment: @enginer Yes they means that you should access route defined in controller: `$http.post('/', {formType....`

Comment: @malcolm this is http://prntscr.com/i1la2c

Comment: i changed my code  `$http.post('/', {formType....` but same error @malcolm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST 405 (Method Not Allowed) API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321950/post-405-method-not-allowed-api)

Comment: in my request stackoverfloaw i added my github project link @Mcsky you can see the controller's annotation.do you need my project symfony without api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainController.php` add `POST` to allow this method.

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     path="/",
     *     methods={"POST"}
     * )
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed but same error Łukasz D. Tulikowski, did  you think that i need a Postman for my project ?

Comment: Because in your browser, `Requested URL` is not the one you defined in `path`.  You should use `http://localhost:8002/api/` or similar to your repository. To find out use `bin/console debug:router` from `app/api` directory.

Comment: you have raison Łukasz D. Tulikowski and thanks for your help.